# Jenkins/Hudson fails when trying to retrieve code from CVS

Tags: hudson, cvs, jenkins, cvsnt

Trying to configure Jenkins CI. Currently just running it from the .war (eventual intention as a service). Jenkins is aware of the CVS executable (i.e. will read the version [Concurrent Versions System (CVSNT) 2.0.62.1817 (client/server)]).

The .cvspass is not specified, because they apparently do not play nice with CVSNT (which prefers to keep passwords in the registry.) I've specified the password in the job config by using the :pserver:user:passg@server:/dir pattern for CVSROOT, which I found suggested in some places. Regardless of whether I run using that, or :pserver:userg@server:/dir as the CVSROOT I get the blinking red ball, jenkins stuck with a nearly full progress bar for 2 and a half minutes. It then fails. The console output yells with something like

> FATAL: hudson.scm.ChangeLogSet.iterator()Ljava/util/Iterator;
>   java.lang.AbstractMethodError: hudson.scm.ChangeLogSet.iterator()Ljava/util/Iterator;
>     at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:282)
>     at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:279)
>     at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:596)
>     at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1400)
>     at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
>     at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:175)

Both CVSROOTs I'm using provide no trouble with TortoiseSVN. I've found some mention of difficult of logging into SVN from jenkins as a service and related user/system issues, but considering I'm running it from the .war I don't think that's the issue.

EDIT:

Interestingly the console log if I use an invalid user or password recognizes such.

> cvs [checkout aborted]: authorization failed: server  rejected access to /dir for user FOO
>   FATAL: CVS failed. exit code=1
>   Finished: FAILURE

which indicates that Hudson is talking to the CVS server and authenticating, but something else goes wrong.

/EDIT

Cheers

Comment: Your error does not look like an access error. Can you check if it downloaded anything in to your workspace? It looks like it is failing while creating a changelog. What version are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer to the question found, thanks to rpetti on #jenkins on freenode. Problem was I had switched between Hudson and Jenkins and there were some incompatible configuration files that were mucking things up. Deleting and recreating the home directory solved the problem.

Comment: Do you mean the home directory of the user running the Hudson server?

Answer (score 0):

CVSNT 2.0.62.1817 is very very old and has [several known security issues](http://march-hare.com/cvspro/security.htm).  Please upgrade to the latest 2.8.01.